# Css poll result rounded

Tags: html, css

I'm making a website, and I'm having some trouble with my poll results. I've searched on google and i still haven't found anything to help me out. I have tried a css but it completely doesn't work. I just get a white block. I'm trying to make the poll results look like this:

[image]

but I can't. How would I do this.

Here is my current code :

```
.Yellow {
  background-color: rgb( 255, 255, 255 );
  position: absolute;
  left: 132px;
  top: 836px;
  width: 164px;
  height: 165px;
  z-index: 260;
}
.Green {
  background-color: rgb( 182, 183, 182 );
  position: absolute;
  left: 132px;
  top: 836px;
  width: 164px;
  height: 165px;
  z-index: 259;
}
.Red {
  background-color: rgb( 81, 108, 120 );
  position: absolute;
  left: 132px;
  top: 836px;
  width: 164px;
  height: 165px;
  z-index: 258;
}
.Cyan {
  background-color: rgb( 220, 177, 61 );
  position: absolute;
  left: 132px;
  top: 836px;
  width: 164px;
  height: 165px;
  z-index: 257;
}
```

Html:

```
<div class="Yellow"></div>
                <div class="Green"></div>
                <div class="Cyan"></div>
                <div class="Red"></div>`
```

Comment: why not use a chart like http://www.highcharts.com/demo/pie-donut ?

Comment: i think u need html5 to make a shape like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getting something like that would be very difficult with css, I would recommend drawing it with javascript in a canvas.

You would have something like:

```
var ctx = document.getElementById('myCanvas').getContext('2d');
ctx.strokeWidth = 10;

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.strokeColor = color1;
ctx.arc(x,y, 0, angle1);
ctx.stroke()

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.strokeColor = color2;
ctx.arc(x,y, angle1, angle2);
ctx.stroke()

...
```

where x,y is the center of the circle, color1, color1, etc are strings for each color, and percent1, percent2, etc. are the angles to start and end each segment.

you could also probably do this with html5's svg support, but I am less familiar with that, and I don't think it is as well supported by browsers (could be wrong though).